# how to append value to a dropdownlist from modal window without page refresh in laravel???

Tags: php, laravel

I just want to append the value to the dropdownlist from modal window.

[image]

When I click Add new link popup modal will display to create new department value. After I created that modal window will be closed and that added value should append on Department dropdownlist without page refresh.

Can anyone help me...?

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your code as of now and what measures you have tried, to make it work.

Comment: yes jquery can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely just something to the effect of:

```
var new_option = $("#textbox_id").val();

$("#my_select_id").append('<option value="' + new_option + '">' + new_option + '</option>');
```

Where #textbox_id is the ID of the text box in your popup window, and #my_select_id is the ID of the dropdown box.

It's not really got anything to do with Laravel.